# Where is my Twitter oauthToken and oauthTokenSecret?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have just created a Twitter "App" for a simplistic conference demo in which my software tool is supposed to do a post to Twitter programmatically via dotnet. I am using the `LinqToTwitter` library from github. I was easily able to locate my `Consumer Key (API Key)`, `Consumer Secret (API Secret)`, `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` here:

> https://apps.twitter.com/app/xxxxx/keys

But LinqToTwitter also requires an `oauthToken` and `oauthTokenSecret` which I cannot find anywhere in my Twitter app settings or account settings. Where can I find these two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a chunk of c# sample code that works great, and discovered that those additional 2 keys are unnecessary (or autogenerated perhaps). Here is the simple code that works GREAT for simply doing a twitter post to your own account:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace TwitterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tweet = new Twitter();
            tweet.SendTweet("Test from Visual Studio @ " + DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("Tweet sent!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Twitter
    {
        private string oAuthConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"];
        private string oAuthConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"];
        private string accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"];
        private string accessTokenSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessTokenSecret"];
        string oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

        public void SendTweet(string message)
        {
            string authHeader = GenerateAuthorizationHeader(message);
            string postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);

            HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
            authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            authRequest.Method = "POST";
            authRequest.UserAgent = "OAuth gem v0.4.4";
            authRequest.Host = "api.twitter.com";
            authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            authRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }

            WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
            authResponse.Close();
        }

        private string GenerateAuthorizationHeader(string status)
        {
            string signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
            string version = "1.0";
            string nonce = GenerateNonce();
            double timestamp = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            string dst = string.Empty;

            dst = string.Empty;
            dst += "OAuth ";
            dst += string.Format("oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", ", Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", ", Uri.EscapeDataString(nonce));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_signature=\"{0}\", ", Uri.EscapeDataString(GenerateOauthSignature(status, nonce, timestamp.ToString())));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_signature_method=\"{0}\", ", Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureMethod));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_timestamp=\"{0}\", ", timestamp);
            dst += string.Format("oauth_token=\"{0}\", ", Uri.EscapeDataString(accessToken));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_version=\"{0}\"", Uri.EscapeDataString(version));
            return dst;
        }

        private string GenerateOauthSignature(string status, string nonce, string timestamp)
        {
            string signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
            string version = "1.0";
            string result = string.Empty;
            string dst = string.Empty;

            dst += string.Format("oauth_consumer_key={0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerKey));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_nonce={0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(nonce));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_signature_method={0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureMethod));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timestamp);
            dst += string.Format("oauth_token={0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(accessToken));
            dst += string.Format("oauth_version={0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(version));
            dst += string.Format("status={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(status));

            string signingKey = string.Empty;
            signingKey = string.Format("{0}&{1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthConsumerSecret), Uri.EscapeDataString(accessTokenSecret));

            result += "POST&";
            result += Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthUrl);
            result += "&";
            result += Uri.EscapeDataString(dst);

            HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1();
            hmac.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey);

            byte[] databuff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
            byte[] hashbytes = hmac.ComputeHash(databuff);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashbytes);
        }

        private string GenerateNonce()
        {
            string nonce = string.Empty;
            var rand = new Random();
            int next = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                next = rand.Next(65, 90);
                char c = Convert.ToChar(next);
                nonce += c;
            }

            return nonce;
        }

        public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
        {
            DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
            return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You need to set up your App.config thusly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConsumerKey" value="xxx"/>
    <add key="ConsumerSecret" value="xxx"/>
    <add key="AccessToken" value="xxx"/>
    <add key="AccessTokenSecret" value="xxx"/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```